# How to convert a string into list with one element in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string which I want to convert to a list with only one element in it.

`a = abc 
print list(a)`

`output : ['a','b','c']`

`Expected o/p = ['abc']`

What is the proper way to do it ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply use `[..]`:

```
a = 'abc'
b = [a]
print(b)
```

`[..]` is [*list notation*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), you can feed it a comma-separated list of values. For instance `[1,4,2,5,'a',1+2,4/3,3.1415]`,... Or as specified in the documentation:

> *(..) The most versatile is the list, which can be written as a list of comma-separated values (items) between square brackets. Lists might contain items of different types, but usually the items all have the same type.*