# Quick Sort Recursion in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I have been studying the quick sort algorithm below and have not been able to understand why [pivot] needs to be returned in brackets and why it needs to be returned at all.  Doesn't the output of the function just need to run the new arrays(less and greater) through the existing function and then get the pivot value like the first time it was called?

```
def quick_sort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    else:
        pivot = arr.pop()

    greater = []
    less = []
    for i in arr:
        if i > pivot:
            greater.append(i)
        else:
            less.append(i)
    return quick_sort(less) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater)

arr1 = [7,8,9,6,5,4,7,8,9]

quick_sort(arr1)
```

Comment: because you're merging lists into one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string into list with one element in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592960/how-to-convert-a-string-into-list-with-one-element-in-python)

Comment: @Sayse but why does the pivot value need to be returned in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, you need it otherwise you'd lose an element from the list every time you call the function

Comment: The pop() removes an element from the list, so you have to explicitly put it back into the returned list, or you will lose an item on every recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is trying to merge three arrays into one. For example:

`mergedArr = [1,2,3]+ [4] + [5,6,7]
print(mergedArr) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Wrapping the pivot inside the bracket will just explicitly turn it into a list so the python program could append everything together